# Java - Zip to file dir issue

Tags: java, file, io, zip

I'm still working on the same app from the other question, I was going fine till I started to work on the ZipExtractToFile void, code works fine with the files in the root of the zip but fails with dir, here's the output from the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: minecraft\achievement\bg.png (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.hachisoftware.mmi.system.Util.ZipExtractToFile(Util.java:56)
at com.hachisoftware.mmi.MinecraftModInstaller.startSystem(MinecraftModInstaller.java:51)
at com.hachisoftware.mmi.MinecraftModInstaller.main(MinecraftModInstaller.java:27)
```

and here is the code:

```
public static void ZipExtractToFile(File inZip, File outDir) throws IOException
{
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(inZip));
    if(!outDir.exists())
    {
        outDir.mkdir();
    }
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    for (ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry(); ze != null; ze = zis.getNextEntry()) 
    {
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(outDir + "\\" + ze.getName())));

        if(ze.isDirectory())
        {
            File dir = new File(ze.getName());
            dir.mkdir();
            continue;
        }

        for (int read = zis.read(buffer); read != -1; read = zis.read(buffer)) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

    zis.close();
}
```

The error is at:

```
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(outDir + "\\" + ze.getName())));
```

Comment: For starters, don't create `File` objects using string concatenation. Use the `File(String parent, String child)` constructor. If you still get an exception, post an update in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are using this line prematurely:

```
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(outDir + "\\" + ze.getName())));
```

This will [throw an exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String%29) since `FileOutputStream` expects a file, not a directory, and at this stage you are not sure if `outDir + "\\" + ze.getName()` is a file or not.

You should put that line after

```
if(ze.isDirectory()) {...}
```

Secondly, if you know that you're creating a new directory, or a file, and you know its parent; it would be better to use this constructor:

```
public File(File parent, String child)
```

See the [relevant Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29).

Using code like `outDir + "\\" + ze.getName()` is more likely to cause errors if you're not careful.